# Using WebSocket with Flash?

Tags: flash, html, websocket

I found [web-socket-js](http://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js) for running WebSocket in Flash.

If I run WebSocket under Flash, can all browsers with Flash player installed support this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all but a few more than the web browsers that have native support for websockets today (I know that at least Google Chrome, has native support for it since 6 months or so).

From the [README](http://github.com/gimite/web-socket-js/blob/master/README.txt):

> It should work on:
>
> - Google Chrome 4 or later (just uses native implementation)
> - Firefox 3.x, Internet Explorer 8 + Flash Player 9 or later
>
> It may or may not work on other browsers such as Safari, Opera or IE 6. Patch for these browsers are appreciated, but I 
>   will not work on fixing issues specific to these browsers by myself.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding Firefox WebSocket must be (called && used && renamed) as MozWebSocket.